# Never instantiate objects in the constructor?

Tags: php, oop, constructor

Is it bad instantiating objects in the constructor like this below?

```
class Foo
{
    public function fooMethod() {
        return 'foo method';
    } 
}

class Too
{
    public function tooMethod() {
        return 'too method';
    } 
}

class Boo
{
    public $foo;
    public $too;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo = new Foo();
        $this->too = new Too();
    }
}
```

If so, how bad can it be? How should it be done properly?

Comment: If you don't do that how else will you declare an element of foo in your class?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Pass it in via the constructor.

Comment: why would this be bad?! its what constructors are for...

Comment: @WayneWhitty That would require the caller to know that the implementation uses `Foo` and `Bar` objects internally. This is an implementation detail that likely should be hidden. It means you couldn't redesign `Boo` so it uses `NewFoo` intead of `Foo`

Answer (score 3):

Manually instantiating classes inside another class creates implicit dependencies, which are quite hard to maintain - you will have a hard time detecting what needs to be changed if you ever need to change those `Foo` and `Too` classes.

So, a better way of managing dependencies is:

```
class Foo
{
    private $_bar;

    function __construct(Bar $bar)
    {
         $this->_bar = $bar;
    }
}
```

This way, your object dependency is explicit. Another advantage of doing this, is that some PHP frameworks, (Laravel, Zend, Symfony), allow for an automatic dependency resolution. It means, that you don't instantiate your object manually, only via some sort of factory - like this (Laravel):

```
$foo = App::make('Foo');
```

And an `App` factory automatically detects your `Foo` class dependencies with some reflection magic and injects them appropriately. Other frameworks have similar capabilities, too.

Also, there are some general principles in OOP, called `SOLID` which help to develop better OOP design. One of them - `D`, stands for `Dependency Inversion`. What it means, is that you should avoid `hard` dependencies, like in your code. Instead, both `Foo` and `Bar` classes should depend on an `interface`, like this:

```
interface BarInterface
{
    function doBar();
}

class Bar implements BarInterface
{
    function doBar()
    {
        print "Doing BAR";
    }
}

class Foo
{
    /**
     * @var BarInterface
     */
    private $bar;

    function __construct(BarInterface $bar)
    {

        $this->bar = $bar;
    }
}
```

Now, if you ever need to change that `Bar` class with something else, all hell won't break loose, if your replacement also implements that `BarInterface`.

Comment: Also, while following `SOLID` principles may seem like an overkill for a small project, i'd still recommend doing so. Making a good object-oriented design isn't all that easy, and requires a lot of practice and experience. So, following good practices may slow down your development speed initially, but soon you'll see that maintaining and extending your project goes way smoother than usual, and it pays off. Also, you won't be able to make a good OOP design for a large project, without making several tries on a smaller ones.

Comment: @TwiStar: Thanks. Can I ask - what is the different if I don't use interface but I do this instead in `Foo`- `function __construct($bar)`?

Comment: Using an interface ensures that you'll use your dependencies correctly. If you typehint an interface - you know what methods does injected class have, and what they should do. But what does `$bar` do? You have no clue. Also, be aware, that eventually you'll have to write code that will be used by other developers, so it's a good thing to write code that will be as clear as possible to anyone, who uses it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not inherently bad.

The downside is that it decreases the "testability" of your class, simply because `Boo` is now dependent on the existence `Foo` and `Too`.

Comment: Using an object Factory is a good way round this, meaning that you can mock the factory returns to mock objects

Comment: @ Mark Baker - how do you use an object Factory for doing this then? thanks!

Comment: @tealou: to reply to someone, type the at-symbol, type the first couple of letters **with no intervening space** and press tab to get an auto-complete menu. Other people may not see your message otherwise (Wayne will be notified of everything under his answer regardless, since he owns it, but Mark will not unless explicitly notified).

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the size of your project.

On large projects, or long term projects, it should be changed slightly.

Ideally, you would refactor it implement [Dependency Injection pattern](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/dependency-injection-in-php--net-28146), and maybe use a Factory to instantiate it.

Some sample code:

```
interface FooInterface { function fooMethod(); } 
class Foo implements FooInterface { function fooMethod(){return 'Foo';} }

interface TooInterface { function tooMethod(); } 
class Too implements FooInterface { function tooMethod(){return 'Too';} }

class Boo
{
    public $foo;
    public $too;

    public function __construct(FooInterface $foo, TooInterface $boo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
        $this->too = $boo;
    }
}

class BooFactory
{
    public static function create()
    {
        return new Boo(new Foo, new Too);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad for the answer. Could you please show an example how this can be done using a Factory? thanks!

Comment: Added for your example. You should read the article I linked to in order to better understand what Dependency Injection is.

Comment: can I ask- what if Foo needs to depend on lots of other classes? The the list to be passed in the `Foo`'s constructor will be very long isnt? For instance, `public function __construct(FooInterface $foo, TooInterface $boo, PooInterface $poo, etc, etc ,etc, etc, etc)` - it looks too much don't you think? Or is it normal?

Comment: @tealou , are you trying to create god object?

Comment: @sectus: what is an god object?

Comment: @sectus: so it is a bad thing then?

Comment: @sectus: I'm working on DI. This is my attempt so far http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58709/dependency-injection-dependency-injection-container-mvc-for-php-webapp#58709 Any thing near DI?

Answer (score 1):

It depends of your requirement and the classes.
Let's says that every call to the constructor of Foo/Too you will execute a huge query to the database to get data, in that scenario I would opt to use [lazy instantiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization).

Of course, it's a good practice to initialize your properties on the constructor, but on real life performance could your enemy.

Example:

```
class Boo {
   private $foo = null;
   private $too = null;
   public function __construct() {
      //Do something else
   }
   public function getFoo() {
      if (is_null($this->foo)) {
         $this->foo = new Foo();
      }
      return $this->foo;
   }
   public function getToo() {
      if (is_null($this->too)) {
         $this->too = new Too();
      }
      return $this->too;
   }
   public function aMethodThatUsesFoo() {
      $foo = $this->getFoo();
      $foo->fooMethod();
   }
   public function aMethodThatDoesntUsesFoo() {
      echo "Hello!, I don't need foo or too to execute this method";
   }
}
```

if you use this class only to execute `aMethodThatDoesntUsesFoo()`, it will never call the constructors of Foo/Too.

```
$boo = new Boo();
$boo->aMethodThatDoesntUsesFoo();
```

if you will only execute `aMethodThatUsesFoo()`, it will only instantiate `Foo`

```
$boo = new Boo();
$boo->aMethodThatUsesFoo();
```

You can do this by static methods as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes please - could you please show me an example of Laze initialization?

Comment: what if `Boo` is a controller, `Foo` is a model that fetches articles from a db and it requires the db connect ($connection) - so where should I pass this $connection from? `$boo = new Boo($connection);`? but $connection has nothing to do with the controller.

Comment: @tealou
If the models needs a connection to the DB, I will use the `Singleton` pattern to make it global, so I don't need to send it as a parameter.

And I could put this `Singleton` in a `Factory` object with a method like `setConnection($connection)`, that will change the connection if you need to use other DB adapters (such us SQLite for testing).

Good questions! ;)

Comment: thanks. but I'm told to avoid singleton pattern... I have tried to use DI in my MVC app here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58709/dependency-injection-dependency-injection-containers-in-mvc-web-app#58709 can you take a look and let me know whether I'm doing it right or wrong? thanks.